# Searching for scenarios in Sparx EA

Tags: sql, enterprise-architect, scenarios

Does anyone have a query sql query allowing them to search for all scenarios under a given package?  This is for SPARX Exterprise Architect 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me, but alas I cannot navigate from there to the use case that I defined the scenario under (in the search results).

`select s.ea_guid as CLASSGUID,s.Scenario, s.ScenarioType as 'Type',  class.name as 'Class Name'
,package.name as 'Package Name' ,package_p1.name as 'Package level -1',package_p2.name as 'Package level -2',package_p3.name as 'Package level -3'
from (((((t_objectscenarios  s
inner join t_object class on s.object_id = class.object_id)
inner join t_package package on class.package_id = package.package_id)
left join t_package package_p1 on package_p1.package_id = package.parent_id)
left join t_package package_p2 on package_p2.package_id = package_p1.parent_id)
left join t_package package_p3 on package_p3.package_id = package_p2.parent_id)
where class.name like '<Search Term>%'`

Comment: EA uses the CLASSGUID and CLASSTYPE columns, which are hidden in the results, for the Find in Diagrams / Project Browser functions. Your query does not include a CLASSTYPE at all, and the ea_guid you return is from the scenario itself - but the scenario is never shown in project browser or diagrams. You need to include the ea_guid and Object_Type columns from the "class" table for it to work: select class.ea_guid as CLASSGUID,class.Object_Type as CLASSTYPE,s.Scenario......